# dpkg snippet isn't working for me when fixing / installing dockbar

Tags: dpkg

I'm trying to use this code from webupd8 to fix the problem I have. It seems it didn't work.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/smplayer_0.6.9+svn3595-1ppa1~maverick1_i386.deb
```

Here is the output from my attempt to install dockbar :

```
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-all var/apt/cache/archives/dockmanager_0.1.0~bzr80-0ubuntu1~10.10~dockers1_i386.deb
 dpkg: error processing var/apt/cache/archives/dockmanager_0.1.0~bzr80-0ubuntu1~10.10~dockers1_i386.deb
 (--install):  cannot access archive:
 No such file or directory Errors were encountered while processing: 
 var/apt/cache/archives/dockmanager_0.1.0~bzr80-0ubuntu1~10.10~dockers1_i386.deb
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Can you please edit your post to tell us what advice it is that you are following?

Answer (score 1):

I think i fixed it already

check out here ...
[dockbar installing error](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1697593):

1. `sudo apt-get -f install`
2. `sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/dockmanager_0.1.0~bzr80-0ubuntu1~10.10~dockers1_i386.deb`
3. `sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 0):

At the very least (of what seems to be a highly hacky "fix" in the first place), you're missing a `/` before `var` in your path.

But as I say in my comment, we need to know what you're trying to do to give you informed advice.

Comment: i think i miss that one, the real thing is, I have problem installing dockbar x in my ubuntu 10.10 and i found this link from webupd8 on how to fix it [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/fix-dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-x.html) and it seems my didn't work